# BAT file to open another bat file in a different folder

Tags: batch-file

Is this the correct way to call a BAT file located in a different folder?

call "C:\program files...\test.bat"

I can't move the program bat file but my startup bat is located in another location than the program it is call.

Answer (score 1):

```
pushd C:\program files...\test.bat\..\
call test.bat
popd
```

Is this what you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, how you are doing it is fine.

```
call "C:\your path\your batch.bat"
```